# Is there a way to resolve this plugin issue

Tags: python, qgis

```
2023-11-16T06:45:30     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/Emma/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\wap_plugin-master\wap_plugin.py", line 869, in run
              self.resetTool()
              File "C:\Users/Emma/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\wap_plugin-master\wap_plugin.py", line 664, in resetTool
              self.coord_select_tool.reset()
             AttributeError: 'WAPlugin' object has no attribute 'coord_select_tool'
```

i have been trying all best but can't resolve it

```
if hasattr(WAPlugin, 'coord_select_tool'):
    print("The WAPlugin object has the coord_select_tool attribute")
else:
    print("The WAPlugin object does not have the coord_select_tool attribute")
```

I've tried this but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.